# How to prevent alphabetical sorting for python bars with matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm plotting some categorical data using a bar chart. Matplotlib keeps sorting my x-axis alphabetically even when I sort my dataframe values.
Here's my code :

```
fig3, new_ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(25/3,5))
summary = tsa.source.sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
new_ax.bar(summary.index, summary.values, color=my_colors)
new_ax.legend()
bar_heights(new_ax) # custom function to get the values on top of bars
simpleaxis(new_ax) # custom function to define an axis to please my boss...
new_ax.set_ylabel('Effectifs')
new_ax.set_xlabel("Type d'arme")
new_ax.grid(False)
```

Output :
[image]

And yet here's what summary looks like and that's the order I want to see on my chart :

```
famas            2214.0
aut_typebruit     759.0
grena             200.0
flg                78.0
douze              72.0
sept               53.0
dtype: float64
```

Here's a link to a sample of my data :
https://files.fm/u/wumscb4q
import it with this line :

```
tsa.source = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=';', index_col=0)
```

And here my functions :

```
def simpleaxis(ax):
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
    ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

def bar_heights(axes):
    for rect in axes.containers[0]:
        height = rect.get_height()
        rect.axes.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., height+3,
            '%d' % int(height),
            ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue. Care to post a [mcve]?

Comment: done, I think...

Comment: Not quite *minimal*. What about `plt.bar(['foo', 'bar'], [1, 2])`? Does it sort the bars alphabetically?

Comment: Yes it does...!

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted - perfectly legitimate question and an issue I've also encountered.  I up-voted it back to neutral.

Comment: I recently discovered the same issue with dataframes with matplotlib 2.2.3. Therefore, I am skeptical of the answer for version upgrade.

Answer (score 16):

### The issue

This is [a bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9312) in matplotlib < 2.2.0 where the X axis is always sorted even if the values are strings. That is why the order of the bars is reversed in the following plot.

```
x = ['foo', 'bar']
y = [1, 2]
plt.bar(x, y, color=['b', 'g'])
```

[image]

### The fix

Upgrade matplotlib to 2.2.0 or higher. The same code produces the expected result with these versions.

[image]

### The workaround

If you cannot or do not want to upgrade matplotlib you can use numbers instead of strings, then set the ticks and labels to the correct values:

```
index = range(len(x))
plt.bar(x, y, color=['b', 'g'])  # use numbers in the X axis.
plt.xticks(index, x)  # set the X ticks and labels
```

[image]

### The Pandas way

You can use `Series.plot` which might be convenient for you since your data is already in the form of a `Series`, but be aware that pandas plots things differently. Use the keyword argument `rot` to control the rotation of the labels.

```
s = pd.Series(y, index=x)
s.plot(kind='bar',rot=0, color=['b', 'g'])
```

[image]

Comment: I have matplotlib version 3.6.0, the problem still exists

Comment: @ibilgen Works as expected for me with matplotlib 3.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question because I found a way around but it needs one more line of code to get to the same result and I don't like that :

```
summary.plot(kind='bar', ax=new_ax, color=my_colors, width=0.8)
fig3.autofmt_xdate(bottom=0.2, rotation=0, ha='center')
```

Second line is needed because `summary.plot()` changes the orientation of the xticklabels to vertical...