# change order x axis matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I am trying to get this chart to show the x axis starting at G and ending with A (left to right).  The Udemy instructor wrote this exact same code and generated the desired results - my x axis seems backwards....and of course, the instructor has not addressed the question.

```
def plot_by_woe(df, rotation_of_x_axis_labels = 0):
x = df.iloc[:, 0].apply(str)
y = df['WoE']
plt.figure(figsize = (18,6))
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle = '--', color = 'k')
plt.xlabel(df.columns[0])
plt.ylabel('Weight of Evidence')
plt.title(str('Weight of Evidence by ' + df.columns[0]))
plt.xticks(rotation = rotation_of_x_axis_labels)

df = pd.DataFrame(
[['G',-1.113459],
 ['F',-0.975440],
 ['E',-0.678267],
 ['D',-0.391843],
 ['C',-0.049503],
 ['B',0.358476],
 ['A',1.107830]],
columns = ['grade', 'WoE'])
df

plot_by_woe(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a bug in the matplotlib version I am using ('2.1.2' and earlier)

[How to prevent alphabetical sorting for python bars with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647875/how-to-prevent-alphabetical-sorting-for-python-bars-with-matplotlib)

I have tried a bunch of workarounds but haven't found a solution yet.  At least we have an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, you want to get the following graph, right?

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg3fD.png)

If so, then your function seems to work well, just call it at the end of your code:

```
plot_by_woe(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Elena_Kosourova - yes - your results are what I am after. It seems strange.  When I call the function, the output I provided is generated- I.e., the order of the x axis is backwards….

Comment: Hi BuJay, the only issue that I noticed in your code above was about function body indentation. So I fixed it, and the code ran well. But I guess it was only the matter of mistyping, otherwise with this issue your code wouldn't run at all. If my answer resolved your problem, do you mind marking it as a solution? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Elena - I upvoted but didn't mark as solution.  It looks like there is a bug - see my post below.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

All in all, here's my code:

```
def plot_by_woe(df, rotation_of_x_axis_labels = 0):
    x = df.iloc[:, 0].apply(str)
    y = df['WoE']
    plt.figure(figsize = (18,6))
    plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle = '--', color = 'k')
    plt.xlabel(df.columns[0])
    plt.ylabel('Weight of Evidence')
    plt.title(str('Weight of Evidence by ' + df.columns[0]))
    plt.xticks(rotation = rotation_of_x_axis_labels)

df = pd.DataFrame(
[['G',-1.113459],
 ['F',-0.975440],
 ['E',-0.678267],
 ['D',-0.391843],
 ['C',-0.049503],
 ['B',0.358476],
 ['A',1.107830]],
columns = ['grade', 'WoE'])

plot_by_woe(df)
```